# Basic Integral Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate:
$$\int\frac{–4x^3(x^4–2)^{1/3}}{(x^2+2)(x^2–2)}dx$$

I had so many attempt in solving this equation but I can't find the correct answer .
I am asking anybody's help. Please help me.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you please re-check your parentheses.

Comment: The result is pretty huge. Are you sure this is exactly it, since your first expression was badly written ? (Tip : Use { ... } when setting powers and other stuff, not parentheses)

Comment: What did you come up with so far?

Answer (score 2):

Try to substitute $\left(x^4-2\right)^{1/3}=t$ to arrive at the integral of a rational function. Start with $x^4-2=t^3$ and differentiate this. Then use pratial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding from @szw1710's hint

Let $x^4-2 = t^3$ then $4x^3\ dx = 3t^2\ dt$ and so

$$\begin{align}  
\int\frac{(x^4-2)^{1/3}}{x^4 - 4}\ 4x^3dx &= \int \frac{3t^3}{t^3-2}\ dt \\
&= \int \left(3 + \frac{6}{t^3-2}\right)\ dt \\ &= 3t + \int \frac{6}{t^3-2} \ dt
\end{align}$$

Then let $t = \sqrt[3]{2}u$ we get

$$ \int \frac{6}{t^3 -2}\ dt = \int\frac{3\sqrt[3]{2}}{u^3-1}\ du$$

Now use partial fractions to decompose
$$ \frac{1}{u^3-1} = \frac{A}{u-1} + \frac{B(2u+1)}{u^2+u+1} + \frac{C}{\left(u+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}} $$

which integrates to

$$ \int \frac{1}{u^3-1}\ du = A\ln \big|u-1\big| + B\ln \big|u^2 + u + 1\big| + \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}C\arctan \left( \frac{2u+1}{\sqrt{3}} \right) $$

The result is, how you say, not pretty... But it's doable.

Comment: If were going to use the general power formula, what should be the answer?

Comment: What do you mean by, "general power formula"?

Comment: This one:
$$\int(\frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1})+ C

Comment: Why do you think that can be used here?